# How can a regexp match a string followed by a char, or ending here?

Tags: regex

How can I make a regular expression that will match:

```
abc/123
abc/123/
abc/123/def
```

But that *won't* match:

```
abc/123def
```

In other words, a regexp that would match if the string either:

- ends here
- continues with a `/`

A simple `^abc/123` would match both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
^(.+\/)+\d+(\/.*)?$
```

Explanation:

```
(.+\/)+  at least one character, followed by a slash, at least once
\d+      then the digits
(\/.*)?  an optional slash, then anything (also optional)
```

This will allow stuff like:

```
abc/123
abc/123/
abc/123/def
abc/def/123/ghi/456
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
^abc/123(/.*)?$
```

Comment: Wrong answer, it matches `abc/123def` as well!